# Why does my (debug) Ionic3 app can't be updated if already installed, compiled from another machine?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I regularly switch between 2 machines for developpment, and I always run into the problem that I must uninstall a debug Android App (built and deployed with Ionic3 from the machine A) if I want to deploy a new debug build from machine B.

Is there a config to prevent this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the app, when switching between machines, will keep the same package name, but will be signed with different keystores. 
When building the `debug` version of your app, it will be signed with a debug keystore, which is usually to be found at

```
~/.android/debug.keystore
```

(OSX/Linux)
or

```
%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

(Windows).

You can

- simply copy the keystore from machine 1 to machine 2 (or vice versa) or
- put one of them in your project folder and add it to git (no
  security issues here, it's not the keystore you'll be using when
  building the app for the playstore). This would require you to [create a signing config](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/) to 'tell' gradle where to find the keystore.